# python - cuDF : find dulplicates in a list of names using Levenshtein distance. ValueError when using apply function on cuDF DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates, gpu, cudf

I want to find duplicates (or almost duplicates) in the names of a `people` dataframe and using Levenshtein distance (2 names separated by at most 1 in Levenshtein distance are considered duplicates). This implies to calculate the levenshtein distance between all the names of the DataFrame which is almost 300 000 rows.

input `people` is like:

```
|         name        |
|---------------------|
|         jack        |
|         john        |
|         jack        |
|         jackz       |
```

output should be like:

```
|         name        |     duplicates   |
|---------------------|------------------|
|         jack        |       [0,2,3]    |
|         john        |         [1]      |
|         jack        |       [0,2,3]    |
|         jackz       |       [0,2,3]    |
```

That is why I'm using the cuDF library on a GPU. Using the functions from this library allowed me to accelerate the running a lot, but it is still not sufficient to run on the entire dataframe.

My code is the following

```
import pandas as pd
import cudf


people=pd.read_csv('people.csv')
df1 = people

def filter_rows(row: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:

    # By default, the row doesn't need to be removed
    row["duplicates"] = []

    # Loop over the texts in the other dataframe 
    targets = cudf.Series(list(df1['name']))
    sr = cudf.Series((len(targets)*[row['name']]))
    #edit_distance is part of cudf library and calculates Levenshtein distance between series
    dist=sr.str.edit_distance(targets=targets)
    dist=dist.where(dist<=1).dropna()
    row["duplicates"]=dist.index.to_arrow().to_pylist()

    return row


# Apply the function (this will create a new column called "duplicates", indicating the list of indexes that have names at most 1 levenshtein distance away from the row

people_with_dup = (df1).apply(filter_rows, axis=1)
```

To accelerate the code, I tried to convert the people dataframe into a cudf dataframe, adding this after line 1:

```
people=cu.from_pandas(people)
```

But when running the code I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypingError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cudf/core/indexed_frame.py:2136, in IndexedFrame._apply(self, func, kernel_getter, *args, **kwargs)
   2135 try:
-> 2136     kernel, retty = _compile_or_get(
   2137         self, func, args, kernel_getter=kernel_getter
   2138     )
   2139 except Exception as e:

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/nvtx/nvtx.py:101, in annotate.__call__.<locals>.inner(*args, **kwargs)
    100 libnvtx_push_range(self.attributes, self.domain.handle)
--> 101 result = func(*args, **kwargs)
    102 libnvtx_pop_range(self.domain.handle)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cudf/core/udf/utils.py:298, in _compile_or_get(frame, func, args, kernel_getter)
    295 # precompile the user udf to get the right return type.
    296 # could be a MaskedType or a scalar type.
--> 298 kernel, scalar_return_type = kernel_getter(frame, func, args)
    299 np_return_type = (
    300     numpy_support.as_dtype(scalar_return_type)
    301     if scalar_return_type.is_internal
    302     else scalar_return_type.np_dtype
    303 )

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cudf/core/udf/row_function.py:146, in _get_row_kernel(frame, func, args)
    143 row_type = _get_frame_row_type(
    144     np.dtype(list(_all_dtypes_from_frame(frame).items()))
    145 )
--> 146 scalar_return_type = _get_udf_return_type(row_type, func, args)
    147 # this is the signature for the final full kernel compilation

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/nvtx/nvtx.py:101, in annotate.__call__.<locals>.inner(*args, **kwargs)
    100 libnvtx_push_range(self.attributes, self.domain.handle)
--> 101 result = func(*args, **kwargs)
    102 libnvtx_pop_range(self.domain.handle)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cudf/core/udf/utils.py:144, in _get_udf_return_type(argty, func, args)
    142 # Get the return type. The PTX is also returned by compile_udf, but is not
    143 # needed here.
--> 144 ptx, output_type = cudautils.compile_udf(func, compile_sig)
    146 if not isinstance(output_type, MaskedType):

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cudf/utils/cudautils.py:250, in compile_udf(udf, type_signature)
    248 # We haven't compiled a function like this before, so need to fall back to
    249 # compilation with Numba
--> 250 ptx_code, return_type = cuda.compile_ptx_for_current_device(
    251     udf, type_signature, device=True
    252 )
    253 if not isinstance(return_type, cudf.core.udf.masked_typing.MaskedType):

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numba/cuda/compiler.py:293, in compile_ptx_for_current_device(pyfunc, args, debug, lineinfo, device, fastmath, opt)
    292 cc = get_current_device().compute_capability
--> 293 return compile_ptx(pyfunc, args, debug=debug, lineinfo=lineinfo,
    294                    device=device, fastmath=fastmath, cc=cc, opt=True)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numba/core/compiler_lock.py:35, in _CompilerLock.__call__.<locals>._acquire_compile_lock(*args, **kwargs)
     34 with self:
---> 35     return func(*args, **kwargs)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numba/cuda/compiler.py:269, in compile_ptx(pyfunc, args, debug, lineinfo, device, fastmath, cc, opt)
    262 nvvm_options = {
    263     'debug': debug,
    264     'lineinfo': lineinfo,
    265     'fastmath': fastmath,
    266     'opt': 3 if opt else 0
    267 }
--> 269 cres = compile_cuda(pyfunc, None, args, debug=debug, lineinfo=lineinfo,
    270                     fastmath=fastmath,
    271                     nvvm_options=nvvm_options)
    272 resty = cres.signature.return_type

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numba/core/compiler_lock.py:35, in _CompilerLock.__call__.<locals>._acquire_compile_lock(*args, **kwargs)
     34 with self:
---> 35     return func(*args, **kwargs)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numba/cuda/compiler.py:212, in compile_cuda(pyfunc, return_type, args, debug, lineinfo, inline, fastmath, nvvm_options)
    211 with target_override('cuda'):
--> 212     cres = compiler.compile_extra(typingctx=typingctx,
    213                                   targetctx=targetctx,
    214                                   func=pyfunc,
    215                                   args=args,
    216                                   return_type=return_type,
    217                                   flags=flags,
    218                                   locals={},
    219                                   pipeline_class=CUDACompiler)
    221 library = cres.library

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numba/core/compiler.py:716, in compile_extra(typingctx, targetctx, func, args, return_type, flags, locals, library, pipeline_class)
    714 pipeline = pipeline_class(typingctx, targetctx, library,
    715                           args, return_type, flags, locals)
--> 716 return pipeline.compile_extra(func)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numba/core/compiler.py:452, in CompilerBase.compile_extra(self, func)
    451 self.state.lifted_from = None
--> 452 return self._compile_bytecode()

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numba/core/compiler.py:520, in CompilerBase._compile_bytecode(self)
    519 assert self.state.func_ir is None
--> 520 return self._compile_core()

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numba/core/compiler.py:499, in CompilerBase._compile_core(self)
    498         if is_final_pipeline:
--> 499             raise e
    500 else:

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numba/core/compiler.py:486, in CompilerBase._compile_core(self)
    485 try:
--> 486     pm.run(self.state)
    487     if self.state.cr is not None:

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numba/core/compiler_machinery.py:368, in PassManager.run(self, state)
    367 patched_exception = self._patch_error(msg, e)
--> 368 raise patched_exception

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numba/core/compiler_machinery.py:356, in PassManager.run(self, state)
    355 if isinstance(pass_inst, CompilerPass):
--> 356     self._runPass(idx, pass_inst, state)
    357 else:

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numba/core/compiler_lock.py:35, in _CompilerLock.__call__.<locals>._acquire_compile_lock(*args, **kwargs)
     34 with self:
---> 35     return func(*args, **kwargs)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numba/core/compiler_machinery.py:311, in PassManager._runPass(self, index, pss, internal_state)
    310 with SimpleTimer() as pass_time:
--> 311     mutated |= check(pss.run_pass, internal_state)
    312 with SimpleTimer() as finalize_time:

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numba/core/compiler_machinery.py:273, in PassManager._runPass.<locals>.check(func, compiler_state)
    272 def check(func, compiler_state):
--> 273     mangled = func(compiler_state)
    274     if mangled not in (True, False):

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numba/core/typed_passes.py:105, in BaseTypeInference.run_pass(self, state)
    102 with fallback_context(state, 'Function "%s" failed type inference'
    103                       % (state.func_id.func_name,)):
    104     # Type inference
--> 105     typemap, return_type, calltypes, errs = type_inference_stage(
    106         state.typingctx,
    107         state.targetctx,
    108         state.func_ir,
    109         state.args,
    110         state.return_type,
    111         state.locals,
    112         raise_errors=self._raise_errors)
    113     state.typemap = typemap

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numba/core/typed_passes.py:81, in type_inference_stage(typingctx, targetctx, interp, args, return_type, locals, raise_errors)
     79     infer.seed_type(k, v)
---> 81 infer.build_constraint()
     82 # return errors in case of partial typing

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numba/core/typeinfer.py:1039, in TypeInferer.build_constraint(self)
   1038 for inst in blk.body:
-> 1039     self.constrain_statement(inst)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numba/core/typeinfer.py:1386, in TypeInferer.constrain_statement(self, inst)
   1385 if isinstance(inst, ir.Assign):
-> 1386     self.typeof_assign(inst)
   1387 elif isinstance(inst, ir.SetItem):

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numba/core/typeinfer.py:1459, in TypeInferer.typeof_assign(self, inst)
   1458 elif isinstance(value, (ir.Global, ir.FreeVar)):
-> 1459     self.typeof_global(inst, inst.target, value)
   1460 elif isinstance(value, ir.Arg):

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numba/core/typeinfer.py:1559, in TypeInferer.typeof_global(self, inst, target, gvar)
   1558 try:
-> 1559     typ = self.resolve_value_type(inst, gvar.value)
   1560 except TypingError as e:

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numba/core/typeinfer.py:1480, in TypeInferer.resolve_value_type(self, inst, val)
   1479     msg = str(e)
-> 1480 raise TypingError(msg, loc=inst.loc)

TypingError: Failed in cuda mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Untyped global name 'list': Cannot determine Numba type of <class 'type'>

File "../../../../tmp/ipykernel_6251/2531843191.py", line 10:
<source missing, REPL/exec in use?>


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
File <timed exec>:1

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/nvtx/nvtx.py:101, in annotate.__call__.<locals>.inner(*args, **kwargs)
     98 @wraps(func)
     99 def inner(*args, **kwargs):
    100     libnvtx_push_range(self.attributes, self.domain.handle)
--> 101     result = func(*args, **kwargs)
    102     libnvtx_pop_range(self.domain.handle)
    103     return result

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cudf/core/dataframe.py:4383, in DataFrame.apply(self, func, axis, raw, result_type, args, **kwargs)
   4380 if result_type is not None:
   4381     raise ValueError("The `result_type` kwarg is not yet supported.")
-> 4383 return self._apply(func, _get_row_kernel, *args, **kwargs)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/contextlib.py:79, in ContextDecorator.__call__.<locals>.inner(*args, **kwds)
     76 @wraps(func)
     77 def inner(*args, **kwds):
     78     with self._recreate_cm():
---> 79         return func(*args, **kwds)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/nvtx/nvtx.py:101, in annotate.__call__.<locals>.inner(*args, **kwargs)
     98 @wraps(func)
     99 def inner(*args, **kwargs):
    100     libnvtx_push_range(self.attributes, self.domain.handle)
--> 101     result = func(*args, **kwargs)
    102     libnvtx_pop_range(self.domain.handle)
    103     return result

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cudf/core/indexed_frame.py:2140, in IndexedFrame._apply(self, func, kernel_getter, *args, **kwargs)
   2136     kernel, retty = _compile_or_get(
   2137         self, func, args, kernel_getter=kernel_getter
   2138     )
   2139 except Exception as e:
-> 2140     raise ValueError(
   2141         "user defined function compilation failed."
   2142     ) from e
   2144 # Mask and data column preallocated
   2145 ans_col = _return_arr_from_dtype(retty, len(self))

ValueError: user defined function compilation failed.
```

Do you have an idea of why? Or on how can I acccelerate the running more?
thanks

Comment: `people=df.read_csv('people.csv')`: you mean `people=pd.read_csv('people.csv')` (`pd.`, not `df.`)?

Comment: Is there a full traceback? Does the error occur in the `.apply` line?

Comment: Can you provide some data and the expected output please?

Comment: @9769953 the error occures in the `.apply` line indeed

Comment: Does it help if you remove the two `pd.Series` typing annotations?

Comment: @9769953 removing them or changing them for `cudf.Series` doesn't change anything :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a partial answer, with some best practices and a temp solution (unoptimized code), just to unstick you:

1. On overall best practices, I don't recommend transferring data over and over again from CPU to GPU, which is what you do in the function.  It's fastest if you limit the number of transfers to only when it's needed.  GPU accelerated computing is great for highly parallelized workflows, so we want to set up our computation to be as vectorized as possible
2. You don't need apply for this (see example below).  When using cuDF, it's best stay close to the Pandas API,  which the RAPIDS team has vectorized for you, and not try to make your own methods with apply unless you really have to.
3. As for your code, please use this code below as a starting point since it uses the Pandas API and its run all on the GPU. The issue, as I mentioned above, is that it is run serially using a `for` loop (and is very inefficient on the GPU's usage).  Please don't expect a speed up until the data is more at scale

```
import cudf
# import pandas as pd # <-- will work in pandas too

df = cudf.DataFrame({"name": ["jack", "john", "jack", "jackz"]})
b= []

sr = cudf.Series(df["name"])
targets =  cudf.Series(df["name"])
sr.str.edit_distance(targets=targets)
for i in range(len(targets)): # <-- sad panda face for running serially
    dist= sr.str.edit_distance(targets[i])
    dist=dist.where(dist<=1).dropna()
    # print(dist) # this is for you
    b.append(dist.index.values.tolist())
df["duplicates"] = b
print(df)
```

output:

```
    name    duplicates
0   jack    [0, 2, 3]
1   john    [1]
2   jack    [0, 2, 3]
3   jackz   [0, 2, 3]
```

One day, I may circle back to this to show how to do it without the `for` loop...or someone else might before me and that should be considered the **best** answer.